# .NET Maui: Light Mode does not display TextCell

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I want all of my users to have the light theme of .NET Maui (as the dark mode style is not that nice). That's why I added `Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;` to App.xaml.cs to override the AppTheme to the light one. The problem: My TextCells are not getting displayed anymore and the styles of the Entry element are still dark:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As first please try if this approach does helps you**

Android:

In MainApplication.cs add into constructor

```
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```

iOS:

Add into Info.plist new key / value

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key> <!-- For light mode only -->
<string>Light</string>
```

NOTE:

For both platforms works also following
In App.xaml.cs (**project file**, **not** under Platforms\Windows) add into constructor

```
Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;
this.RequestedThemeChanged += (s, e) => { Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light; };
```

**If you will have still problems, than you might check under Resources\Styles\Styles.xaml what is BackgroundColor, PlaceholderColor for Entry (or any control) when Light mode is activated**

For Windows in App.xml file which is inside of Platforms\Windows subfolder set property RequestedTheme

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    x:Class="NetMaui.WinUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
    RequestedTheme="Light"
    xmlns:local="using:NetMaui.WinUI">

</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

Comment: Do you also have a solution for windows?

Comment: My previous answer was edited with instructions for Windows